# Exception while getting data from sqlite database in spinner

Tags: android, sqlite

I am getting java.lang.IllegalStateException when trying to get data in spinner from sqlite database. The data is entered correctly in database and when i am trying to retrieve everything works fine. However problem arises when i am trying to load data in spinner. 
what my code intends to do is to first save the data obtained from web service in sqlite database and load states for a country selected by user.
If u have some better way to do this plz suggest me the link. Following is the LogCat

```
10-06 01:08:38.125: E/CursorWindow(1067): Failed to read row 0, column 1 from a CursorWindow  which has 1356 rows, 1 columns.
10-06 01:08:38.125: D/AndroidRuntime(1067): Shutting down VM
10-06 01:08:38.135: W/dalvikvm(1067): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb2a3bba8)
10-06 01:08:38.165: E/AndroidRuntime(1067): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-06 01:08:38.165: E/AndroidRuntime(1067): Process: com.manish.tabdemo, PID: 1067
10-06 01:08:38.165: E/AndroidRuntime(1067): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity  ComponentInfo{com.manish.tabdemo/com.manish.tabdemo.countrystatelist}:  java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col 1 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor  is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.
10-06 01:08:38.165: E/AndroidRuntime(1067):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
10-06 01:08:38.165: E/AndroidRuntime(1067):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
10-06 01:08:38.165: E/AndroidRuntime(1067):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
10-06 01:08:38.165: E/AndroidRuntime(1067):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
10-06 01:08:38.165: E/AndroidRuntime(1067):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
10-06 01:08:38.165: E/AndroidRuntime(1067):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
10-06 01:08:38.165: E/AndroidRuntime(1067):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
10-06 01:08:38.165: E/AndroidRuntime(1067):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-06 01:08:38.165: E/AndroidRuntime(1067):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
10-06 01:08:38.165: E/AndroidRuntime(1067):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
10-06 01:08:38.165: E/AndroidRuntime(1067):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
10-06 01:08:38.165: E/AndroidRuntime(1067):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-06 01:08:38.165: E/AndroidRuntime(1067): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col 1 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.
10-06 01:08:38.165: E/AndroidRuntime(1067):     at android.database.CursorWindow.nativeGetString(Native Method)
10-06 01:08:38.165: E/AndroidRuntime(1067):     at android.database.CursorWindow.getString(CursorWindow.java:434)
10-06 01:08:38.165: E/AndroidRuntime(1067):     at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:51)
10-06 01:08:38.165: E/AndroidRuntime(1067):     at com.manish.tabdemo.DatabaseHandler.getAllCountries(DatabaseHandler.java:85)
10-06 01:08:38.165: E/AndroidRuntime(1067):     at com.manish.tabdemo.countrystatelist.loadCountrySpinnerData(countrystatelist.java:80)
10-06 01:08:38.165: E/AndroidRuntime(1067):     at com.manish.tabdemo.countrystatelist.onCreate(countrystatelist.java:48)
10-06 01:08:38.165: E/AndroidRuntime(1067):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
10-06 01:08:38.165: E/AndroidRuntime(1067):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
10-06 01:08:38.165: E/AndroidRuntime(1067):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
10-06 01:08:38.165: E/AndroidRuntime(1067):     ... 11 more
10-06 01:09:21.635: I/Process(1067): Sending signal. PID: 1067 SIG: 9
```

Following is the code

**countrystatelist.java**

```
public class countrystatelist extends Activity implements OnItemSelectedListener{


private static final String NAMESPACE = "riderapp";
private static final String METHOD_NAME = "getCountryandStateList";
private static final String URL = "http://demo.php.otssolutions.com/ridersapp/admin/server.php?wsdl";
private static final String SOAP_ACTION = "riderappAppServer";
String Status;
String array;
String temp;
TextView textView;
String truee = "true";
DatabaseHandler db;
Spinner country_spinner;
Spinner state_spinner;
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.countrystatelist);
    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.result);
    country_spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.country);
    state_spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.state);
    country_spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    loadCountrySpinnerData();
     AsyncCallWS task = new AsyncCallWS();
        task.execute();
        db = new DatabaseHandler(this);
}

public void callservice(){
    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
    request.addProperty(truee, "true");
    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
            SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
    HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
    try{
        androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);

    SoapObject result = (SoapObject)envelope.bodyIn;
    Status = result.getProperty(0).toString();


    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void loadCountrySpinnerData() {
    // database handler
    DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());

    // Spinner Drop down elements
    List<countrystate> lables = db.getAllCountries();

    // Creating adapter for spinner
    ArrayAdapter<countrystate> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<countrystate>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, lables);

    // Drop down layout style - list view with radio button
    dataAdapter
            .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    // attaching data adapter to spinner
    country_spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
}

private void loadStateSpinnerData(String label) {
    // database handler
    DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());

    // Spinner Drop down elements
    List<countrystate> lables = db.getAllStates(label);

    // Creating adapter for spinner
    ArrayAdapter<countrystate> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<countrystate>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, lables);

    // Drop down layout style - list view with radio button
    dataAdapter
            .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    // attaching data adapter to spinner
    state_spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
}

private class AsyncCallWS extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
        Log.i("OTS+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++", "doInBackground");
        callservice();
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        Log.i("OTS---------------------------------------", "onPostExecute");
    //textView.setText(Status);

        String s[] = new String[350];
        String country_id[] = new String[350];
        String country_name[] = new String[350];
        String state_id[] = new String[700];
        String state_name[] = new String[700];
        StringTokenizer tokens = new StringTokenizer(Status, ",");
        for(int i=0;i<339;i++){
            s[i] = tokens.nextToken();
            }
        for(int i=0;i<339;i++){

            country_id[i] = s[i].substring(s[i].indexOf("id=")+3, s[i].indexOf(";", s[i].indexOf("id=")));
            country_name[i] = s[i].substring(s[i].indexOf("country_name=")+13, s[i].indexOf(";", s[i].indexOf("country_name=")));
             state_id[i] = s[i].substring(s[i].indexOf("sid=")+4, s[i].indexOf(";", s[i].indexOf("sid=")));
             state_name[i] = s[i].substring(s[i].indexOf("state_name=")+11, s[i].indexOf(";", s[i].indexOf("state_name")));
             db.addEntry(new countrystate(country_id[i], country_name[i], state_id[i], state_name[i]));
        }

        List<countrystate> list = db.getAllCountries();
        for( countrystate t : list){
            Log.e("OTS", t.get_id()+t.get_countryname()+t.get_stateid()+t.get_statename());
        }
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        Log.i("OTS===========================================", "onPreExecute");
        textView.setText("Validating..Please Wait");
    }
    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
        Log.i("OTS*******************************************", "onProgressUpdate");
    }


}

@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
        long arg3) {

    String label = arg0.getItemAtPosition(arg2).toString();

    loadStateSpinnerData(label);
}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {


}
}
```

**DatabaseHandler.java**

public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

```
 private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
 private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "countrystate";
 private static final String TABLE = "countrystatelist";
 private static final String Id = "id";
 private static final String country_name = "countryname";
 private static final String state_id = "stateid";
 private static final String state_name = "statename";

 public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

 @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String CREATE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE + "("
                + Id + " INTEGER ," + country_name + " TEXT,"
                + state_id + " INTEGER," + state_name + " TEXT" + ")";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);
    }

 @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // Drop older table if existed
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE);

        // Create tables again
        onCreate(db);
    }

 void addEntry(countrystate cs) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(Id, cs.get_id()); 
        values.put(country_name, cs.get_countryname());
        values.put(state_id, cs.get_stateid());
        values.put(state_name, cs.get_statename());

        // Inserting Row
        db.insert(TABLE, null, values);
        db.close(); // Closing database connection
    }

 countrystate getoneentry(int id) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

        Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE, new String[] { Id,
                country_name , state_id, state_name }, Id + "=?",
                new String[] { String.valueOf(id) }, null, null, null, null);
        if (cursor != null)
            cursor.moveToFirst();

        countrystate cs = new countrystate(cursor.getString(0),
                cursor.getString(1),cursor.getString(2),cursor.getString(3));

        return cs;
    }

 public List<countrystate> getAllCountries() {
        List<countrystate> list = new ArrayList<countrystate>();
        // Select All Query
        String selectQuery = "SELECT " + country_name +" FROM " + TABLE ;

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        // looping through all rows and adding to list
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                countrystate cs = new countrystate();
                cs.set_id(cursor.getString(0));
                cs.set_countryname(cursor.getString(1));
                cs.set_stateid(cursor.getString(2));
                cs.set_statename(cursor.getString(3));
                list.add(cs);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }

        // return contact list
        return list;
    }

 public List<countrystate> getAllStates(String c) {
        List<countrystate> list = new ArrayList<countrystate>();
        // Select All Query
        String selectQuery = "SELECT " + state_name + " FROM " + TABLE + " WHERE " + Id + " = " + c;

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        // looping through all rows and adding to list
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                countrystate cs = new countrystate();
                cs.set_id(cursor.getString(0));
                cs.set_countryname(cursor.getString(1));
                cs.set_stateid(cursor.getString(2));
                cs.set_statename(cursor.getString(3));
                list.add(cs);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }

        // return contact list
        return list;
    }

 public int getEntryCount() {
        String countQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);
        cursor.close();

        // return count
        return cursor.getCount();
    }
}
```

**countrystate.java**

```
public class countrystate{


String id;
String country_name;
String state_id;
String state_name;

public countrystate(){

}

public countrystate(String id,String country_name,String state_id,String state_name){
    this.id = id;
    this.country_name = country_name;
    this.state_id = state_id;
    this.state_name = state_name;
}

public String get_id(){
    return this.id;
}

public String get_countryname(){
    return this.country_name;
}

public String get_stateid(){
    return this.state_id;
}

public String get_statename(){
    return this.state_name;
}

public void set_id(String id){
    this.id = id;
}

public void set_countryname(String country_name){
    this.country_name = country_name;
}

public void set_stateid(String state_id){
    this.state_id = state_id;
}

public void set_statename(String state_name){
    this.state_name = state_name;
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `getAllCountries()`, your `SELECT` has only one column but you are trying to access data from 4 columns with `getString(0)`...`getString(3)`. Make sure your `SELECT` selects at least as many columns.

Comment: Thanks a lot for making me understand my problem. how should i do it then? i just want country names

Comment: Remove the `getString(1)` ... `getString(3)` or add at least three more columns to the `SELECT`.

Comment: @ laalto i changed the code to this  if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
             do {
                 countrystate cs = new countrystate();
                
                 cs.set_countryname(cursor.getString(1));
                 
                 list.add(cs);
             } while (cursor.moveToNext());
         }   but still getting same error

Comment: Yes because column indexing starts from 0 and not 1.

Answer (score 1):

> 10-06 01:08:38.125: E/CursorWindow(1067): Failed to read row 0, column
> 1 from a CursorWindow  which has 1356 rows, 1 columns.

And

> 10-06 01:08:38.165: E/AndroidRuntime(1067): Caused by:
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col 1 from
> CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before
> accessing data from it.

From this exception, you can understand the reason behind this exception. This exception says that you are trying to read Column 1 which isn't exist because there is only a single column created.

**Suggestion:**

1. Don't use column number directly, best practice is to use [Cursor.getColumnIndex(String columnName)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#getColumnIndex%28java.lang.String%29) method.
2. Don't use separate arrays, best practice is to use ArrayList where object can be any user defined object like Student, College, Country, etc.

**Bad practice:**

String s[] = new String[350];
String country_id[] = new String[350];
String country_name[] = new String[350];
String state_id[] = new String[700];
String state_name[] = new String[700];

**Best practice:**

```
ArrayList<Country> listCountry = new ArrayList<>();
Country objCountry = new Country();
objCountry.setCountryID(1);
objCountry.setCountryName("India");
listCountry.add(objCountry);
```

Comment: @user3828709 implement the best practices mentioned above and then update here with whatever status.

Comment: @Paresh Mayani i changed the code to this  cs.set_countryname(cursor.getColumnIndex(country_name));  But it gives error The method set_countryname(String) in the type countrystate is not applicable for the arguments (int)

Comment: @user3828709 you need a good book of Android application development! Sorry.